# Fit (resize/compress) overflowing content in a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap. I have div with class="row" and three columns inside with divs in each column.

The third column overflows outside the row div, which could be fixed by giving `padding-right` to row div. But it still repeats when resized to smaller size.

While resizing from md to sm to xs, the column divs overlap during the transition.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful to include [some code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If all of your columns (col-*-*) add up to 12 you should be alright. If it's an image that's overflowing (which it sounds like it is) you can add the `img-reponsive` class to it. This will set `max-width: 100%` which sounds like the issue but I can't be sure without a code sample.